# Classic Elder Scrolls guilds in TESO?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I found a Fighters Guild in TESO and now I wonder whether or not some other guilds are in the game. As far as I know there are 4 guilds that are always present in Elder Scrolls games (Fighter, Mage, Thief, Assassin).

I'm really interested in the Dark Brotherhood since I play a rogue but it would also be nice to know where the other guilds are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now there are three NPC guilds in the game, which you can join - all offering a unique skill line for your character:

- The **Fighters Guild** is pretty much what you expect them to be. They've taken a massive contract to fight back Molag Bal's Dark Anchors and all Daedra.
- The **Mages Guild** is pretty much what you expect them to be as well. They're trying to preserve knowledge throughout the times of war.
- The **Undaunted** are new in the series. They're a group of adventurers trying to prove their worth and they're a bit like a group of posers. They want to fight the biggest, strongest, meanest creatures and win.

Unfortunately, some guilds didn't make it right into launch , but they're scheduled to be added at a later date, most likely later this year:

- The **Dark Brotherhood** will be added later. They're still quite the same as in the previous games and will most likely offer contracts and bounties.
- The **Thieves Guild** will be back as well. They didn't release any details so far, but it's quite likely that its introduction will also introduce a crime/stealing system.

Also, there are quite a few other groups in the game. Some you'll be able to join, but they won't necessarily grant you direct bonuses or skills. Warning: spoiler ahead!

> - The **Eyes of the Queen** are a network of spies working outside the Aldmeri Dominion's laws (as far as necessary) and subject only to Queen Ayrenn herself.
> - The **Morag Tong** are quite similar to the Dark Brotherhood, although they're quite focused on Morrowind.
> - The **Shadowscales** are a group of Argonians bringing the *gift of Sithis* to those worthy. Another group of assassins (is there some pattern? ;)).
> - The **Beldama Wyrd** are a circle of witches from Glenumbra. They're pretty much classic druids, but only women.
> - The **Companions** you've met in **Skyrim** appear in **ESO** as well, but you're not able to become one of them.
> - And probably many others I just forgot to mention right now... this list is definitely incomplete.